# Eclipse debugger "Failed to read variables"

Tags: eclipse, node.js

Any idea why Eclipse Luna does not present the variables when trying to debug Node project? Instead of variables we see "Failed to read variables" as shown here

[image: eclipse debugger error]

Comment: What plugin is used?

Comment: I'm using node Eclipse which I have installed on other computer as well. I have no idea why on one computer it works and on the other it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

First, you should learn what actual plugin you are using.

For Node.js is Nodeclipse `/noʊdˈklɪps/` http://www.nodeclipse.org/ This effort that is not backed by any business, there were several people spending personal time, including me.

You don't even spell right, that mean you did no effort to read project pages.

Second, if it works on one computer and does not on other, then it is bug.
You should raise issue specifying exact OS, Java, Eclipse and Nodeclipse plugin versions (as visible Window -> Preferences -> Nodeclipse) and steps how to reproduce at

https://github.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/